# Why PhpStorm won't validate sass correctly?

Tags: validation, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, scss-lint

I am having a hard time getting PhpStorm to validate my `scss` correctly.

It is throwing unnecessary errors.

Like this:

In this picture, for instance, it is obvious that `$color-name` exists in the parameter listing.
[image]

What is it that might be causing this problem?

Comment: works fine for me. What IDE version do you use? Does it happen in scratch files or in actual `.scss` files?

Comment: Hi @lena I am using version 2019.2.3

Comment: @lena The problem is also occurring in WebStorm latest version.
and it's happening in `.scss` files

Comment: can't reproduce; does the issue persist after caches invalidation?

Comment: @lena Hi I was able to fix this problem when I deleted the .idea and .sass-cache hidden directories.
I am not sure what was causing the problem, what do you think could it be? and why?

Comment: no idea, sorry:(